# Custom view theming for fields referenced to another node in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

In my Drupal 7 site I have 2 node types tour and game. Tour contains 10 games. I'm using References 7.x-2.0-beta3 for creating references in tour for game.

I'm trying to create a view block with one tour and all games in it.
How can I display game fields in simple html table ( tags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use a relationship between the tour and the games it references. Then under fields you must use this relationship.